# Reading a file with 4 records, UI shows 36K tasks

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading a file from s3 with just 4 records, i see 36k tasks for a count on the dataset on the UI + my memory for 3 clusters show half full(60GB in total). Does this seem alright for a situation like this?

```
ctx.textFile(filename,1).mapPartitions(....)
```

## Update 1

```
public static void main(String[] args){
sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(Constants.APP_NAME)
                        .set("spark.io.compression.codec", "lzf")
                        .set("spark.speculation", "true")
                        .set("spark.cleaner.ttl", "10000")
                        .set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseG1GC");

            ctx= new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
                        JavaRDD<Object1> FileDataJavaRDD = batchDao.fileRDD (javaSparkCtx, FilePath);

            FileDataJavaRDD .count();
}


public static JavaRDD<Object1> fileRDD (JavaSparkContext ctx, String filePath) {
        return ctx.textFile(FilePath,1).mapPartitions(new FlatMapFunction<Iterator<String>, Object1>() {
            @Override
            public Iterable<Object1> call(Iterator<String> stringIterator) throws Exception {
                final Object1 currentDayFile = new Object1();
                List<Object1> list = new ArrayList<Object1>();
                while (stringIterator.hasNext()) {
                   String line = stringIterator.next();
                   String[] parts = line.split("\u0001", -1);
                    currentDayFile.setId(parts[1]);
                   ..................few setters
                    list.add(currentDayFile);
                return list;
            }

                return list;
            }
        });



   public class Object1 implements Externalizable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final String DELIMITER = "\u0001";

        public String id1;
        public String id2;

    .....few getter and setters
  @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput stream) throws IOException {
        stream.writeObject(this.id1);}

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        this.id1= (String) stream.readObject();
}
```

[image: stages]
[image: memory usage]

Comment: Definitely not alright . Could you post the entire code and file content?

Comment: edited my post. Please see

Comment: This implementation looks strange. Where do you use filerdd? What are you trying to do?

Comment: apologies! modified the code. I am just reading a file from s3 and just doing a count.

Comment: Ok. What is object1? It seems that you are doing something or else this should take a few seconds and have no foot print

Comment: Object1 is just a model class with some getters and setters which implements externalizable..That is pretty much it. running this on a 3 node cluster on aws.

Comment: Could you please just call count after reading the file. At the end of that line.

Comment: I did but the ui shows 36k tasks.. I don't know where thats happening internally.. It takes around 1 minute to complete.

Comment: Can you try this code with a lcoal file? Also how many stages and jobs did you could see on UI?

Comment: @amit_kumar - when i run this locally it just finishes like in a second with just having 1/1 tasks for the count. Do you suspect any issue with reading from s3/cluster?

Comment: It may be, You should attach screenshots of what it looks like on UI for jobs and stages when you run your code using S3.

Comment: @amit_kumar - edited my post with the details you asked. Let me know if you need additional details.

Comment: What is in the logs? I do not see the task complete. Do they complete ever?
Are there any failed stages?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113954/discussion-between-springstarter-and-amit-kumar).